# ImportError: cannot import name 'UNSIGNED' from 'botocore' (unknown location)

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, importerror, aiobotocore

i was trying to checking products on my bucket using the async lib `aioboto3` but when importing lib ,this message accured

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emir/Scrivania/facts/bucket chekcer/bucket_checker.py", line 2, in <module>
    import aioboto3
  File "/home/emir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioboto3/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aioboto3.session import Session
  File "/home/emir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioboto3/session.py", line 9, in <module>
    import aiobotocore.session
  File "/home/emir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiobotocore/session.py", line 1, in <module>
    from botocore import UNSIGNED, translate
ImportError: cannot import name 'UNSIGNED' from 'botocore' (unknown location)
```

I already tried to set up an 'venv' and reinstalled the lib but same error showed,what do i do ?